# they lost only to a couple of Russian dogs -- in what manner did they lose to them?

Tags: comprehension

Example with [a context](http://www.vox.com/2015/3/7/8163347/space-monkey-miss-baker):

> Those two monkeys were the first American animals, and some of the first animals in general, ever to travel into space and make it back alive (**they lost only to a couple of Russian dogs**).

I don't think I'm following that part. They lost to a couple of Russian dogs in what manner?

Comment: the dogs were there first. Laika, iirc was the first dog [in fact animal of any sort] in space. (I looked at the ref article after that fact - seems I remembered correctly;)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One needs to understand **(1)** how to parse the sentence and **(2)** the role of *lost only to*.  Consider the following hierarchical tree:

```
Those two monkeys 
    were the first American animals
    , and some of the first animals in general, 
    ever to 
          travel into space 
          and 
          make it back alive 
(they lost only to a couple of Russian dogs).
```

Simplified into three sentences:

- Those monkeys were the first American animals (to do something).
- Those monkeys were some of the first animals (to do something).
- They `lost`<sub>[ranking=not_first]</sub> `only to`<sub>[ranking=second]</sub> a couple of dogs.

In the race to space-and-back-alive, the monkeys **lost**. They **lost to** the two dogs and **only to** the two dogs.  They did not **lose to** any other animals.

Answer (score 5):

At the time, the US and Russia were competing to be the first country to put a man in space. The monkeys were the first American animals in space, but lost the international competition to the Russian dogs. Only a couple dogs were launched into space, so they didn't lose by a large margin. If the Russians had made many successful launches, the "only" and "couple" would have been left out.